# Function for testing if a row in a dataframe doesn't contain a given element

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like

```
a <- c(2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 4, 3)
c <- c(2, 7, 9)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

df
#   a b c
# 1 2 5 2
# 2 3 4 7
# 3 4 3 9
```

and I want to get back the row without number `2`, in my example it is just second row.

Comment: You mean output should be 2nd and 3rd row?

Comment: Your solution is for columns, I would like to have the row of the dataframe that doesn't contain 2, in the example the second row.

Answer (score 3):

Using rowSums or colSums:

```
# data
a <- c(2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 4, 3)
c <- c(2, 7, 9)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

df
#   a b c
# 1 2 5 2
# 2 3 4 7
# 3 4 3 9


# get rows with no 2
df[ rowSums(df == 2, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
#   a b c
# 2 3 4 7
# 3 4 3 9

# get columns with no 2
df[ , colSums(df == 2, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, drop = FALSE ]
#   b
# 1 5
# 2 4
# 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `Reduce` with `==` to get the rows

```
df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `==`, 2)),]
#  a b c
#2 3 4 7
#3 4 3 9
```

and `any` with `lapply` to select the columns

```
df[!sapply(df, function(x) any(x== 2))]
#  b
#1 5
#2 4
#3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using some set functions. First, where are the positions of the twos?

```
is_two <- apply(df, 1, is.element, 2)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Now, which rows are all FALSE?

```
no_twos <- apply(!is_two, 1, all)
df[no_twos,]
 a b c
2 3 4 7
```